# How to return a list of the 10 top names based on multiple criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to get a top 10 list from a data table based on two different criteria.

| Name | Sex | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Taylor | f | 268.2341742 |
| Taylor | f | 252.2535105 |
| Halle | f | 250.7678059 |
| Christian | m | 410.1501907 |

What I want is a list of the top 10 women (or men) unique by total. What I've been able to get is a list of the top 10 women, but it includes duplicates, which is what I don't want.

I've been able to get a list of the top 10 women by total, but it includes duplicates.

Here is the formula I'm using:

```
 =INDEX(Results[Name],MATCH(UNIQUE(LARGE(FILTER(Results[SinclairTotal],Results[Sex]="f"),[@Rank])),Results[SinclairTotal],0))
```

Where `Results` is the table that includes all of the data and the table to fill in has the following columns:

| Rank | Name | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be not the easiest task, as you need to take care of the aggregation of totals etc., but a `LET()` statement should help you to keep things clean and provide you with a spilled array. Generally, the `LET()` allows you to assign names to intermediate values. I extended the example data a bit to have a more comprehensive example (see below) stored in range `A1:C15`.

**Input data:**

| Name | Sex | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Taylor | f | 268 |
| Taylor | f | 252 |
| Halle | f | 251 |
| Christian | m | 410 |
| abc | m | 216 |
| def | f | 508 |
| abc | m | 608 |
| ijk | f | 174 |
| kjen | m | 208 |
| vhjre | f | 302 |
| vhjre | f | 658 |
| ajk | m | 528 |
| ertz | f | 148 |
| kjen | m | 596 |

---

**Case 1: Returning Aggregate Totals**

The formula put in practice looks as follows:

```
=LET(
    data, $A$1:$C$15,
    criteria, "f",
    topN, 3,
    filteredData, FILTER(data, INDEX(data, , 2) = criteria),
    uniqueNames, UNIQUE(INDEX(filteredData, , 1)),
    totals, SUMIFS(INDEX(data, , 3), INDEX(data, , 1), uniqueNames, INDEX(data, , 2), criteria),
    sortedNames, INDEX(uniqueNames, MATCH(LARGE(totals, SEQUENCE(topN)), totals, 0)),
    sortedTotals, INDEX(totals, MATCH(LARGE(totals, SEQUENCE(topN)), totals, 0)),
    HSTACK(SEQUENCE(topN), sortedNames, sortedTotals)
)
```

Now to the important part, what is going on here: First we define the range of the data (as mentioned above), which we call `data`. Next, we define the `criteria` according to which we want to filter the data, e.g., "f" as well as the number of observations called `topN` that we want to return. I used here the top 3 for expositional purposes, but this can be changed flexibly.

Next, we filter the data based on the criteria defined from our `data` and extract the `uniqueNames`, which we need to aggregate the totals and return the correct data in the end. The next step is a simple `SUMIFS()` statement to aggregate the totals for each unique name based on which we decide if it is included in the topN or not. Once we obtained the `totals`, we can use this information to extract both the names and the totals that are part of the topN. Basically, here we obtain the row index for the `INDEX()` function by matching the totals using a combination of `MATCH()`, `LARGE()` and `SEQUENCE()`. The same idea applies to returning the aggregate totals. The final step is to return the rank, as well as the obtained names and totals in a table like structure. For this purpose, we use the `HSTACK()` function to horizontally stack multiple arrays.

The output for top 3 with criteria "f" is as follows:

| Rank | Name | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | vhjre | 960 |
| 2 | Taylor | 520 |
| 3 | def | 508 |

The output for top 3 with criteria "m" is as follows:

| Rank | Name | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 824 |
| 2 | kjen | 804 |
| 3 | ajk | 528 |

---

**Case 2: Returning Maximum Totals** (based on comment)

In case you want to return maximum totals, you need to slightly adjust the `LET()` statement because you also need to compute the `maxTotals`. The adjusted formula put in practice looks as follows:

```
=LET(
    data, $A$1:$C$15,
    criteria, "f",
    topN, 3,
    filteredData, FILTER(data, INDEX(data, , 2) = criteria),
    uniqueNames, UNIQUE(INDEX(filteredData, , 1)),
    totals, SUMIFS(INDEX(data, , 3), INDEX(data, , 1), uniqueNames, INDEX(data, , 2), criteria),
    maxTotals,MAXIFS(INDEX(data,,3),INDEX(data,,1),uniqueNames,INDEX(data,,2),criteria),
    sortedNames, INDEX(uniqueNames, MATCH(LARGE(totals, SEQUENCE(topN)), totals, 0)),
    sortedTotals, INDEX(maxTotals, MATCH(LARGE(totals, SEQUENCE(topN)), totals, 0)),
    HSTACK(SEQUENCE(topN), sortedNames, sortedTotals)
)
```

This `LET()` statement has basically two adjustments. The first is the additional computation of `maxTotals`, which simply uses the `MAXIFS()` instead of the `SUMIFS()`. The `SUMIFS()` is also in this case required, because you make the decision based on the aggregate totals. The second adjustment in this statement is in the line of `sortedTotals` because you want to return not the `totals` but the `maxTotals.` All other aspects remain the same.

The output for top 3 with criteria "f" is as follows:

| Rank | Name | Max Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | vhjre | 658 |
| 2 | Taylor | 268 |
| 3 | def | 508 |

The output for top 3 with criteria "m" is as follows:

| Rank | Name | Max Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 608 |
| 2 | kjen | 596 |
| 3 | ajk | 528 |

---

*Additional explanations:*

In case you want to return any intermediate step rather than the final result to trace whats going on, you can change in the `LET()` statement the line of `HSTACK()` as follows to return, e.g., the sortedNames:

```
    result, HSTACK(SEQUENCE(topN),sortedNames, sortedTotals),
    sortedNames
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The only thing I noticed is that I'm not looking to return the sum of the totals. Just the top total for each name. Is this doable?

Comment: @Harlan See my edit to address this issue.

Comment: Thanks. This was great! And I learned something new. Question: can you use Table references with LET to make it more dynamic?

Comment: @Harlan Well, at least you could use named ranges, I think once you transfer the data to an Excel Table it become, e.g., "Table1". I think you could adjust this name accordingly and then use in the `LET()` statement the following for the data: `data, Table1,`